# Unable to port forward of Kubernetes service

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Currently running spark service in GKE cluster and able to see the service is up and running

```
NAME           TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                               AGE
spark-master   NodePort    10.X.X.X   <none> 9090:32072/TCP,7077:32577/TCP,8998:31067/TCP     34d
```

Now when trying to port forward with below command it's getting timed out

```
kubectl port-forward --namespace mynamespace service/spark-master 7077:7077
```

Its throwing an error

```
error: timed out waiting for the condition
```

But I am able to port forward other services running in this cluster
Any idea how to resolve or debug?

Comment: can you check 3 things
1) Firewall rules preventing 7077 port
2) Any existing service running on port 7077
3) Forwarding to a different port

Also if possible provide the manifest file which is used for deploying your application or the steps you followed for deploying the application.